# Is it possible to use one pointer to insert a node into a BST?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I wonder if I can insert without the trailing pointer y. Here is my code:

```
def tree_insert(root, key):
    z = TreeNode(key)
    y = None
    x = root
    while x:
        y = x
        if z.val < x.val:
            x = x.left
        else:
            x = x.right
    if y is None:
        root = z
    elif z.val < y.val:
        y.left = z
    else:
        y.right = z
```

Thank you!

Comment: This function is not correct: when `root` is None, the caller will never get to see the inserted node, since `root` is a locally variable in this function.

Comment: @Maras, that will not help: the `root` in the main program would still be `None` after the call.

Comment: @trincot Yeah, my bad, the pointer outside the function won't change.

Comment: To be fair I don't really see the point of this question. You can either use the additional pointer to the parent, that is y in this case, or use additional if statements. There is almost no difference either in the performance or memory consumption. I guess the author wants to know if there is a better way to write that function and unfortunately, the answer is no.

Comment: @Maras, see my answer though for some ideas...

Comment: @trincot Your answer is perfectly fine, but apart from answering the question, I still think it's good to point out that omitting the y variable is not really helping in any way, it's just a matter of refactoring the code, not necessarily in a better way.

Comment: Did you read about the recursive alternative? I am of the opinion that recursion is the better way here.

Comment: Well, you've rewritten his iterative code to a recursive one. Both of them are still perfectly correct (apart from the missing return statement in case of root being None), maybe the recursive one is slightly easier to read and understand. It's very subjective which one is better.

Comment: As you said, the code doesn't work if the root is None.  It needs to be changed. After fixing that, it's not a very big deal if he uses additional pointer for the parent or two if statements, or even changes the function to the recursive approach. It's mostly a visual difference, unless you really care for that few bytes for the y variable. If that's the case I suggest changing the language, since Python consumes a lot of memory by itself. I know that you've just answered his question and you did it very well.

Comment: I'm only saying, for the person who asked the question, that it is possible to avoid this additional pointer, but it doesn't make the code better, at least not objectively. If he asked such question I expect that he's quite new to programming and he's looking for a better code. I'm pointing out that his code is okay, I would only change the variables' names for something more meaningful than 'x', 'y' and 'z'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function has an issue: when the function assigns `root = x`, then the caller will not know about it, since `root` is a local variable.

You can solve this in many ways. One is that you have a contract that the function always returns the root.

To avoid an `y` you can just assign `z` as soon as you know where it should go:

```
def tree_insert(root, key):
    z = TreeNode(key)
    if not root:
        return z  # new root
    x = root
    while True:
        if z.val < x.val:
            if not x.left:
                x.left = z
                return root
            x = x.left
        else:
            if not x.right:
                x.right = z
                return root
            x = x.right
```

So use it as follows -- always assigning back to `root`:

```
root = None
root = tree_insert(root, 5)
root = tree_insert(root, 2)
root = tree_insert(root, 4)
root = tree_insert(root, 8)
root = tree_insert(root, 1)
```

You can even save more variables, if you turn the function into a recursive one:

```
def tree_insert(root, key):
    if not root:
        return TreeNode(key)
    if key < root.val:
        root.left = tree_insert(root.left, key)
    else:
        root.right = tree_insert(root.right, key)
    return root
```

Again, this function returns the root, and the caller must take it into account.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to programming. What do you mean by "contract"? What should I do to globally change the root in my original code?

Comment: With contract, I mean that you agree with yourself, or whomever will use your code, that the caller of the function must use the return value to set the (global) root.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much!